# Access returning value from a function like macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, header-files

Recently, I was going through the code of JOS Kernel (developed at MIT for mostly learning purpose to help beginners like me) and come up with a small doubt which I think may be trivial but not able to figure out so posting here for help ..

This is a small piece of code from a **".c"** file :-

```
if(n>0)
           {
            nextfree = ROUNDUP((char *) nextfree, PGSIZE);
            result=nextfree;
            nextfree+=n;
            PADDR(nextfree);
           }
```

Corresponding **".h"** file :-

```
/* This macro takes a kernel virtual address -- an address that points above
* KERNBASE, where the machine's maximum 256MB of physical memory is mapped --
* and returns the corresponding physical address.  It panics if you pass it a
* non-kernel virtual address.
*/

    #define PADDR(kva)                      \
    ({                              \
    physaddr_t __m_kva = (physaddr_t) (kva);        \
    if (__m_kva < KERNBASE)                 \
    panic("PADDR called with invalid kva %08lx", __m_kva);\
    __m_kva - KERNBASE;                 \
    })
```

Now I have two questions regarding the above structure -

1. Shouldn't we assign value of `PADDR(nextfree)` to some variable like `var=PADDR(nextfree)` rather than directly calling it as above. How will it work out?
2. Why would someone prefer to write such small and complex definitions in headers files rather than making a function for the designated task that would be easy to grasp.

Comment: It does appear as though the macro will not do anything useful for you; inline definitions tend to be used to optimize performance, and are not intended for "mere mortals to look at".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke a macro, the compiler substitutes the macro definition into your code at that point. There is no "return value" as such, unless the macro happens to expand to something that has a return value.

This construct:

```
 ( { /* ... */ } )
```

is a gcc-specific extension known as a "statement expression", documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It consists of a *compound statement* enclosed in parentheses, and it yields the value of the last expression. (If the last thing before the `; }` isn't an expression, then the whole thing doesn't yield a value.)

The `PADDR()` macro takes a kernel *virtual* address `kva` and yields the corresponding *physical* address. It panics if the virtual address is invalid. (It could have been written as a function, but the authors chose to use a macro, probably for efficiency. An `inline` function could probably have achieved the same goal.)

In the code you've shown that uses `PADDR`:

```
if (n > 0) {
    /* snip */
    PADDR(nextfree);
}
```

the `PADDR` macro is invoked, but the value it yields is discarded. Assuming this isn't an error, this is probably done to force a panic if `nextfree` is not a valid virtual address. The code doesn't use the resulting physical address because it doesn't need it; the check is all it needs.

It still computes `__m_kva - KERNBASE;`, which is probably slightly wasteful, but I doubt that the cost is significant -- and an optimizing compiler is likely to recognize that the result isn't used, and discard the computation.

Comment: `the PADDR macro is invoked, but the value it yields is discarded. Assuming this isn't an error, this is probably done to force a panic if nextfree is not a valid virtual address.` .. Thats what exactly I was looking for .. thanks . Yesssss it is used here for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Well... unpicking this:

1. Notice the parens. This means whatever is inside it will reduce to a single value...
2. Notice the braces: we're defining a new block scope here.
3. Now we're in the new scope, we can safely define whatever variables we like because they won't escape this block.
4. The last statement consists of an expression.
5. Therefore the value of the scope is the value of that expression in the last statement.
6. Therefore the return value of the macro is `__m_kva - KERNBASE`.

So to answer question 1: it does return a value, but in your example snippet this returned value is simply not used. Presumably other code that calls the macro does use that value, though. To answer question 2: that depends. You can do things with macro's which you simply cannot do with functions, like `undefining` them. In this case it seems the programmer needed to replicate common error-checking, and used the translation macro to do it in the sample snippet. (It checks in advance that the next free will not inadvertently attempt to `free` userspace memory or something like that.)